# Problem importing LinkedIn experience and education to Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

I just tried to import my experience and education from LinkedIn, and according to the web page everything worked.  But when I'm redirected to my profile, nothing is there.  I tried logging out and logging back in, but no joy.  I've searched the existing questions, but nothing seems to quite match.  I've tried three times, each time seeming to be successful, but obviously no joy; this doesn't seem to be a transient error.

I'm happy to RTFM or be told I missed an obvious step, but it was a pretty straightforward process and the UI is easy to follow.  I'm not sure how I could have gotten it wrong.

Comment: Currently working on this.  Should be updated soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved.

Comment: Works great, thanks for the prompt response. :)