# Import from linkedin: are there any problem?

Tags: support, jobs, linkedin

I already checked other questions and even tried to set my profile as an active candidate but nothing.

The problem is the same reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85237/problem-importing-linkedin-experience-and-education-to-careers-2-0) but being that question closed I wanted to re-open the question.

Basically when I finish to check all the "Import this one" buttons and I am redirected to my profile page I don't see any update. I even tried the "Import all items below" but with the same result.

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: I've just tried the *Import all items below* button and it worked fine. This was done with an empty profile (invite accepted, nothing filled in). Firefox 26.

Comment: I tried with Firefox 26 and Chrome 32.0.1700.102 m but the result is the same, my profile isn't empty, later I will try to empty the profile and report the result here

Comment: I tested after removing all experiences and every section of profile but the problem is not solved...